# How to use closure to receive async data from a class with delegate in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, delegates, closures

My basic requirement in to listen to a swift package’s variable’s value when connected to a sever and change a published value of same type inside view-model.

The code below is a sample code constructed to explain scenario. This code does not work properly as `isConnected` value is not updated when server is connected.

In the sample code, a Swift package called `ClientPackage` with its class and delegate protocol. Then there is `ViewModel` class which SwiftUI uses to update state of UI and there is a `LocalClient` class which implements `ClientPackage` library. Basically LocalClient is used as an abstract local package to make implementation on same easier inside ViewModel. (I'm not sure if this is the right approach for this.) So I need to change `isConnected` boolean in `ViewModel` when server is connected inside `ClientPackage`.

So I want to fixed this code in order to update `isConencted` value updated. The `connected` variable in `LocalClient` is set correctly from delegate method.

How can I make the closure in `ViewModel.connect()` work?

*P.S. In the real app, I am using Starscream 4.0.4 swift package for `ClientPackage`.*

```swift
// SocketClient.swift
// Xcode 12.3

import Foundation

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    var client: LocalClient?

    @Published var isConnected: Bool?
    
    let token = "12345678" // This is fetched async in real scenario
    
    init() {
        client = LocalClient(token: token)
    }
    
    func connect() {
        client?.connect() { connected in
            self.isConnected = connected
        }
    }
    
}

// Assuming code below is from a local swift package and can be modified

class LocalClient: NSObject {
    
    var coreClient: ClientPackage?
    var connected = false
    
    init(token: String) {
        super.init()
        coreClient = ClientPackage(token: token)
        coreClient!.delegate = self
    }
    
    func connect(_ completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        coreClient?.connectToServer()
        completion(connected)
    }
}

extension LocalClient: ClientPackageDelegate {
    func connectedToServer(_ client: ClientPackage) {
        connected = true
        print("Connected to server")
    }
    
    func disconnectedFromServer(_ client: ClientPackage) {
        connected = false
        print("Disconnected from server")
    }
}

// Assuming code below is from a swift package and cannot be modified

// import Starscream

open class ClientPackage {
    open weak var delegate: ClientPackageDelegate?
    open var socketConnected: Bool?
    open var token: String?
    
    public init(token: String) {
        self.token = token
        self.socketConnected = false
    }
    
    open func didConnect() {
        self.delegate?.connectedToServer(self)
        self.socketConnected = true
    }
    
    open func didDisconnect() {
        self.delegate?.disconnectedFromServer(self)
        self.socketConnected = false
    }
    
    open func connectToServer() {
        // This method connect client to server asynchronously over websocket
        // When connection stable, self.didConnect is called
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {
            self.didConnect()
        }
    }
    
    open func disconnectFromServer() {
        // This method disconnect the connection
        // When connection stable, self.didDisconnect is called
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
            self.didDisconnect()
        }
    }
}

public protocol ClientPackageDelegate: NSObjectProtocol {
    func connectedToServer(_ client: ClientPackage)
    func disconnectedFromServer(_ client: ClientPackage)
}
```

```swift
// ContentView.swift

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var vm = ViewModel()
    var connected: Bool { vm.isConnected ?? false }
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(connected ? "Disconnected" : "Connected"){
                connected ? vm.disconnect() : vm.connect()
            }
            Text(connected ? "Connected" : "Disconnected")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to make the `connected` property of `LocalClient` `@Published`, then update the `isConnected` property of your view model whenever `client.connected` is updated.

`LocalClient` is already conforming to `ClientPackageDelegate` and its `connected` property is updated via the delegate methods, so you simply need to propagate the value of `connected` to your view model, to update the `isConnected` property which your UI observes.

```
class ClientViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    var client: LocalClient?

    @Published var isConnected: Bool = false
    
    let token = "12345678" // This is fetched async in real scenario
    
    init() {
        client = LocalClient(token: token)
        client?.$connected.assign(to: &$isConnected)
    }
    
    func connect() {
        client?.connect() { connected in
            self.isConnected = connected
        }
    }
    
}

// Assuming code below is from a local swift package and can be modified

class LocalClient: NSObject {
    
    var coreClient: ClientPackage?
    @Published var connected = false
    
    init(token: String) {
        super.init()
        coreClient = ClientPackage(token: token)
        coreClient!.delegate = self
    }
    
    func connect(_ completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        coreClient?.connectToServer()
        completion(connected)
    }
}
```

If you want closure based behaviour rather than using `Combine` (which I think is the wrong way to go, since you're already using Combine in your view model anyways), you just need to inject a closure into `LocalClient`, which you execute from your delegate methods whenever the connectivity state changes.

```
class ClientViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    var client: LocalClient?

    @Published var isConnected: Bool = false
    
    let token = "12345678" // This is fetched async in real scenario
    
    init() {
        client = LocalClient(token: token, connectionStateChanged: { [weak self] in self?.isConnected = $0 })
    }
    
    func connect() {
        client?.connect() { connected in
            self.isConnected = connected
        }
    }
    
}

// Assuming code below is from a local swift package and can be modified

class LocalClient: NSObject {
    
    let coreClient: ClientPackage
    var connected = false
    let connectionStateChanged: (Bool) -> Void
    
    init(token: String, connectionStateChanged: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        self.connectionStateChanged = connectionStateChanged
        coreClient = ClientPackage(token: token)
        super.init()
        coreClient.delegate = self
    }
    
    func connect(_ completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        coreClient.connectToServer()
        completion(connected)
    }
}

extension LocalClient: ClientPackageDelegate {
    func connectedToServer(_ client: ClientPackage) {
        self.connected = true
        connectionStateChanged(true)
        print("Connected to server")
    }
    
    func disconnectedFromServer(_ client: ClientPackage) {
        self.connected = false
        connectionStateChanged(false)
        print("Disconnected from server")
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not want to use observableobject class in the local package. I want  to use closure to communicate with local package.

Comment: @NikzJon you don't need `ObservableObject`, you just need `@Published`. Are you targeting <iOS 13 with your local package? Is that the reason why you want to avoid using `Combine`? I don't see any other reason why you'd want closure-based behaviour over Combine, especially when you are using `Combine` in your view model.

Comment: Yes compatibility is a reason. But also I am not very much familiar with complex publishers and all. I have a long way to go this with app and this is only tip of ice burg. So I thought sticking to closure might be easier way to go complex.

Comment: @NikzJon updated my answer with a closure-based solution, but I'd suggest you use the Combine solution instead. It uses no complex publishers whatsoever and results in more concise and cleaner code. So unless you need to target <iOS 13, I really don't see a reason why you'd want the closure based solution instead of the Combine one.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Closure worked great! But after reading your comments, i decided to go with combine. Thanks again.